# How to view Mozilla source files? (.d and .i extemsions)

Tags: mercurial

I have pulled the Mozilla source code from Mercurial, however I have ended up with two versions of each file. One has a **.d** extra extension and the other has a **.i**

e.g. **main.js.d** &  **main.js.i**

Have tried to open the files using a text editor but format is not recognised. Anyone able to advise on the process?

Comment: what is the address you pulled from?  I do not see any files like that.

Comment: what version of Mercurial are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where you pulled your source code from but I did it just fine and did not get this.  This is the command I used:

```
 hg clone --uncompressed http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ src
```

Give it a try and it should work.

Comment: Whenever I try that I receive: <br/> 
 requesting all changesadding changesets <br/>
transaction abort!<br/>
rollback completed<br/>
abort: connection ended unexpectedly <br/>

Comment: @user2648914 are you doing this into a new directory not the old one from your last pull?

Comment: I initially tried the clone method above, but this failed as above. So Instead I did the bundles method.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial#Bundles I am using Ubuntu in VMWare. Network connection for anything else is fine and high speed

Comment: Just tried "hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ src2 " and the same error

Comment: giving this a go: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/935/connection-ended-unexpectedly-when-cloning-a-large-repository

Comment: Using --uncompressed as per link below worked, many thanks for your help ObieMD5 (tried to click up on your post but advises I need 15 rep points...)

Comment: @user2648914 you can check it as answer.  I added the uncompressed part

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Seems this was an UBUNTU releated issue, as recently created a Debian install on  the same machine/vm platform/wifi connection and this was fine.